# Getting the ID of a radio button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Is there a way to get the ID of a radio button using JavaScript?

So far I have:

*HTML*

```
<input type="radio" name="fullorfirst" id="fullname" />
```

*JavaScript*

```
var checkID = document.getElementById(fullname);
console.log(checkID);
```

It outputs as `null`.

Essentially what I want to do is:

```
document.getElementById(fullname).checked = true;
```

...in order to change the radio button `fullname` to be checked on page load.

Answer (score 3):

you should put `fullname` between quotes, since it's a string:

```
document.getElementById("fullname");
```

Answer (score 0):

function checkValue() // if you pass the form, checkValue(form)
{

```
 var form = document.getElementById('fullname'); // if you passed the form, you wouldn't need this line.
 for(var i = 0; i < form.buztype.length; i++)
 {
      if(form.buztype[i].checked)
      {
      var selectedValue = form.buztype[i].value;
      }

 }


 alert(selectedValue);
 return false;
```

}

**Hope this helps.**

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Solution:

```
document.getElementById("fullname").checked = true;
```

Jquery Solution:

```
$("#fullname").prop("checked", true);
```